# hard drives - what is stripe group size given stripe unit size?

Tags: hard-drive, raid-5

If I know a hard drive's stripe unit size is 16 KB, am I able to calculate the stripe group size? For example, is it 4 times 16 as a rule, or does the group size simply need to be some multiple of 16 KB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a question based on a RAID-5 hard drive configuration. There is one drive for parity and four for a stripe group. If a stripe unit is 16KB, then 4 x 16 = 64KB stripe group.